# Server with libpion crashing at request handling

Tags: c++, boost, server, boost-asio

I use the following versions of the libraries: libpion-dev 5.0.6 libboost-all-dev 1.58.0 In the Internet found a simple example of an asynchronous HTTP-server, but it falls in the processing of requests for which the handler is described. In addition, for non-existent resources correctly returns 404 response.

Server code:I use the following versions of the libraries: libpion-dev 5.0.6 libboost-all-dev 1.58.0 In the Internet found a simple example of an asynchronous HTTP-server, but it falls in the processing of requests for which the handler is described. In addition, for non-existent resources correctly returns 404 response.

Server code:

```
#include <boost/bind/arg.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <pion/http/parser.hpp>
#include <pion/http/request.hpp>
#include <pion/http/response_writer.hpp>
#include <pion/http/server.hpp>
#include <pion/tcp/connection.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>

struct fake_server {
    void start() {
        m_server = pion::http::server_ptr(new pion::http::server(8080));
        m_server->add_resource("/test", boost::bind(&fake_server::handle_request, this, _1, _2));
        m_server->start();
    }

    void handle_request(pion::http::request_ptr& _httpRequest, pion::tcp::connection_ptr& _tcpConn) {

        pion::http::response_writer_ptr writer(
                pion::http::response_writer::create(
                _tcpConn,
                *_httpRequest,
                boost::bind(&pion::tcp::connection::finish, _tcpConn)));
        pion::http::response& r = writer->get_response();
        writer->write("hello world");
        writer->send();
    }

    pion::http::server_ptr m_server;
};

int main() {

    fake_server svr;
    svr.start();

    for(;;) sleep(86400);
}
```

Stack of threas, which was crashed:

```
Thread #9 [TEST_pion] 16903 [core: 0] (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault) 
    boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::start_op() at reactive_socket_service_base.ipp:219 0x412918  
    boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::async_send<boost::asio::detail::consuming_buffers<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::allocator<boost::asio::const_buffer> > >, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::allocator<boost::asio::const_buffer> >, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::function2<void, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long> > >() at reactive_socket_service_base.hpp:216 0x41a79e  
    boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::async_send<boost::asio::detail::consuming_buffers<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::allocator<boost::asio::const_buffer> > >, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::allocator<boost::asio::const_buffer> >, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::function2<void, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long> > >() at stream_socket_service.hpp:330 0x41a79e  
    boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::async_write_some<boost::asio::detail::consuming_buffers<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::allocator<boost::asio::const_buffer> > >, boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::allocator<boost::asio::const_buffer> >, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::function2<void, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long> > >() at basic_stream_socket.hpp:732 0x41a79e 
    boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::allocator<boost::asio::const_buffer> >, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::function2<void, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long> >::operator() at write.hpp:181 0x41a79e   
    boost::asio::async_write<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::allocator<boost::asio::const_buffer> >, boost::function2<void, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>&>() at write.hpp:621 0x41acc6   
    pion::tcp::connection::async_write<std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer, std::allocator<boost::asio::const_buffer> >, boost::function2<void, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long> >() at connection.hpp:567 0x41ca4c   
    pion::http::writer::send_more_data<boost::function2<void, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long> >() at writer.hpp:277 0x41ca4c   
    pion::http::writer::send() at writer.hpp:167 0x41cf8f   
    fake_server::handle_request() at TEST_pion.cpp:28 0x41cf8f  
    boost::function2<void, boost::shared_ptr<pion::http::request>&, boost::shared_ptr<pion::tcp::connection>&>::operator()(boost::shared_ptr<pion::http::request>&, boost::shared_ptr<pion::tcp::connection>&) const at 0x7ffff6e8a5c9  
    pion::http::server::handle_request() at 0x7ffff6e8516b  
    boost::function3<void, boost::shared_ptr<pion::http::request>, boost::shared_ptr<pion::tcp::connection>, boost::system::error_code const&>::operator()(boost::shared_ptr<pion::http::request>, boost::shared_ptr<pion::tcp::connection>, boost::system::error_code const&) const at 0x7ffff6e8a25c  
    pion::http::request_reader::finished_reading() at 0x7ffff6e8a3bb    
    pion::http::reader::consume_bytes() at 0x7ffff6e830ec   
    pion::http::reader::consume_bytes() at 0x7ffff6e8374d   
    boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, pion::http::reader, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<pion::http::request_reader> >, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> > >::do_complete at 0x7ffff6e8810b    
    boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::do_complete() at 0x7ffff6e55a84   
    pion::scheduler::process_service_work() at 0x7ffff6e41de1   
    0x7ffff7bc3bc5  
    start_thread() at pthread_create.c:333 0x7ffff5d446aa   
    clone() at clone.S:109 0x7ffff6269e9d
```

In this example, the request http://127.0.0.1:8080/none returns 404 without crash, and http://127.0.0.1:8080/test make crash. I can not understand, what is the reason and how to do it right. Library haven't documentation, maybe something not taken into account. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in the pion library. However, the reason why the request to `/none` returns 404 without crashing is because it's being handled by the `pion` library NOT by the `handle_request` function.

There is an example of using the pion library [here](http://prog-xp.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/creating-simple-web-server-with-pion.html). It may help you discover what's going wrong in the `handle_request` function.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I ran into this also.

In my case it turned out to be differing Boost compile-time options between Boost and Pion DLLs.  Specifically, the option BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG was enabled in one build and disabled in another.  This results in boost::posix_time::ptime having differing sizes between the two, so memory stops mapping to the appropriate members when I cross DLL boundaries.

In my case the fix was to make the compile time options consistent.